# Asynchronous processing of work items from a priority queue

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I just got into a mental block when aysncronously handling work items from a queue

Basically multiple calls can come to a loader class to load files(count the number of lines in file- for example's sake). The loader is supposed to queue these work items and process it according to priority. Enqueing can work in parallel, but the actaul loading of file should be happened sequentially.

However my code works syncronously and execute the whole code sequentially.

```
 public class RequestInfo
    {
        public string filename;
        public ManualResetEvent ManaulEvent;
        public int result;
        public int priority;
    }

    public class Loader
    {
        readonly ConcurrentPriorityQueue<int, RequestInfo> _loadQueue = new ConcurrentPriorityQueue<int, RequestInfo>();
        public async Task<int> NumOfLinesinFile(string filepath, int priority)
        {
            RequestInfo info = new RequestInfo()
            {
                filename = filepath,
                ManaulEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false),
                priority = priority
            };
            _loadQueue.Enqueue(info.priority, info);
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                LoadContent(info);
                info.ManaulEvent.WaitOne();
            });
            await task;
            return info.result;
        }

        async void  LoadContent(RequestInfo info)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => DoWork());
        }

        void DoWork()
        {
            KeyValuePair<int, RequestInfo> quueueContent;
            bool val = _loadQueue.TryDequeue(out quueueContent);
            if (val)
            {
                quueueContent.Value.result = Load(quueueContent.Value.filename, quueueContent.Value.priority);
                quueueContent.Value.ManaulEvent.Set();
            }
        }

        int Load(string filename, int priority)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            return priority;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoFileLoad();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private static async void DoFileLoad()
        {
            Loader loader = new Loader();

            Console.WriteLine(await loader.NumOfLinesinFile("C://file1.txt", 1));
            Console.WriteLine(await loader.NumOfLinesinFile("C://file2.txt", 33));
            Console.WriteLine(await loader.NumOfLinesinFile("C://fil3.txt", 0));
            Console.WriteLine(await loader.NumOfLinesinFile("C://fil3.txt", 6));
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing basically all wrong :) But first, what is ConcurrentPriorityQueue? I mean do you have source code for it (or what nuget package you use for that)?

Comment: The enqueuing will hardly take any time compared to the file processing. So what's the benefit to parallelizing the enqueueing while still sequentially processing the files?

Comment: @Evk https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364/sourcecode?fileId=44488&pathId=1831994732

Comment: @Vikhram it is a priority queue. So higher priority items enqueued later will load earlier

Comment: @Evk this is the nuget package MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want to process items sequentially, it's better to run separate thread for that task, and use `BlockingCollection` together with your `ConcurrentPriorityQueue` (fortunately priority queue does support the right interface for it to be able to be used with `BlockingCollection`. You don't need to start new thread for each item like you do now.

Second, instead of `ManualResetEvent` you can use `TaskCompletionSource` in your case. Here is an example:

```
public class RequestInfo
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    internal TaskCompletionSource<int> TaskSource { get; set; }        
}

public class Loader : IDisposable
{
    readonly BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<int, RequestInfo>> _loadQueue = new BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<int, RequestInfo>>(new ConcurrentPriorityQueue<int, RequestInfo>());
    public Loader() {
        new Thread(Loop)
        {
            IsBackground = true
        }.Start();
    }

    public Task<int> NumOfLinesinFile(string filepath, int priority) {
        RequestInfo info = new RequestInfo() {
            Filename = filepath,
            TaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>(),
            Priority = priority
        };
        _loadQueue.TryAdd(new KeyValuePair<int, RequestInfo>(info.Priority, info));
        return info.TaskSource.Task;
    }

    void Loop()
    {
        foreach (var item in _loadQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
            item.Value.Result = Load(item.Value.Filename, item.Value.Priority);
            item.Value.TaskSource.SetResult(item.Value.Result);
        }                                                    
    }

    int Load(string filename, int priority)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return priority;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        _loadQueue.CompleteAdding();
        _loadQueue.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then, in your example, you are adding each item and awaiting returned task. That means item will be added, then it will be processed, and only then next item will be added. If you want to avoid this - change your code like this:

```
private static async void DoFileLoad() {
    Loader loader = new Loader();
    var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
    tasks.Add(loader.NumOfLinesinFile("C://file1.txt", 1));
    tasks.Add(loader.NumOfLinesinFile("C://file2.txt", 33));
    tasks.Add(loader.NumOfLinesinFile("C://fil3.txt", 0));
    tasks.Add(loader.NumOfLinesinFile("C://fil3.txt", 6));
    while (tasks.Count > 0) {
        var t = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
        tasks.Remove(t);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
    loader.Dispose();
}
```

Note that this is just for this example. In real usage - multiple threads will add items.

Code above is just an example and should be imroved for real usage (and least with proper exception handling).

Comment: Cool. I need a priority queue though- as higher priority items need to be processed first.

Comment: @Jimmy my example uses your priority queue, you might have missed it: ` readonly BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<int, RequestInfo>> _loadQueue = new BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<int, RequestInfo>>(**new ConcurrentPriorityQueue<int, RequestInfo>()**);` < here. So items are processed in order of priority.

Comment: With that answer you answered quite a number of questions from me. Thank you mate.

Comment: Please use Task.Run() -> http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: @piedar I replaced `Task.Factory.StartNew` with just starting new background thread. I think that is more appropriate here than `Task.Run` because we don't need to hold thread pool thread, but just need new thread to run our loop for a long time.

Comment: @Jimmy I guess it was downvoted by piedar because I used Task.Factory.StartNew. It does not matter much in this case anyway, so nothing to worry about (but note I edited question with a better way than StartNew).